# When i use numpy it says - unused import statement .How to fix it?

Tags: python, numpy

I have installed numpy but when I import it, it doesn't work.

```
from numpy import *

arr=array([1,2,3,4])
print(arr)
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\YUVRAJ\PycharmProjects\mycode2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/YUVRAJ/PycharmProjects/mycode2/numpy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/YUVRAJ/PycharmProjects/mycode2/numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from numpy import *
  File "C:\Users\YUVRAJ\PycharmProjects\mycode2\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    x=array([1,2,3,4])
NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your problem is simply that `from numpy import *` is not importing a symbol named **array**. I don't know that package well enough to know why this is true, if you expect that import statement to define **array**.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it works fine for me. How did you install `numpy`? Did you use `pip`?

Comment: are you, perhaps, thinking of Numpy's `ndarray` type?

Comment: it's because you're calling that inside a file called `numpy.py`. update the name of your script to something like `test_numpy.py` and it should work

Comment: How to update the name of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `from numpy import *`

Try using this:

```
import numpy
from numpy import array
```

And then add your code:

```
arr=array([1,2,3,4])
print(arr)
```

---

**EDIT:** Even though this is the accepted answer, this may not work under all circumstances. If this doesn't work, see [adrtam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522733/5721784).

Comment: this won't work. it's because their script is called `numpy.py`

Comment: Thanks it was useful

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you named your script as `numpy.py`, which is a conflict with the module numpy that you need to use. Just rename your script to something else and will be fine.

Comment: Thanks it was useful